# Is it lawful for Muslims to prohibit LGBT people from getting an education?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, homosexuality, education, transgender

Our college made a policy recently which can be summed up like this: you have to sign a paper that says that you will be dropped out without questions if you are not free from LGBT. This is total restriction over LGBT, not LGBT sexual acts on campus or something like that. If found out (before or after graduation) the college administration will lawfully kick you out or revoke you. It shocked LGBT communities in my country because there was no such policy required before.

The majority of my friends are under the assumption that it is a Muslim mission to prevent LGBT spreading given the opportunities (even by prohibiting their education). I don't know either. I don't even know if this question will be black and white amongst Muslims. Being an atheist, I solemnly believe that being LGBT should not be a reason for someone not getting an education.

Our state's constitution embeds the right of education to people, not be seen for what they are. But it gets tricky when our college can have a policy on their own regarding this case.

Is it lawful (in Islamic practices) for Muslims to prohibit LGBT people from getting an education? Does Islam has specific laws about this? If it is not, are Muslims required to do this?

Comment: It's best to stick to [one question](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2965/17163) and ask it well.  We also need to avoid opinion-seeking question, such as "What is your humbled opinion about this?" and "How could I argue with them about this?"  Answers are not a means for differing opinions to compete with one another.  Questions should seek something specific and verifiable, e.g., "Do [some group of Muslims] forbid schools from providing education to LGBT people?"

Comment: Well, not going to be nitpicking or anything. can i ask you a question ?

Comment: first, does deleted question not completely erased from stack exchange ? how can i promotw my question more ?

Comment: in my previous question, i ask a question, "is it right or wrong _____" but.. there is commenter that propose to change question because in islam stackexchange, i cant ask right or wrong.. but in other stackexchange, i can.. so i was in a dilemma whether to ask for opinion (which i know is not advised) or question about its rightness

Comment: and not to be disrespectful, "Do [some group of Muslims] forbid schools from providing education to LGBT people?" provides differences answers to my question..

Comment: It's a "soft delete", so users with enough reputation can see them.  The site works better if we avoid opinion-seeking questions (where anyone's opinion is valid) and stick to questions where answers can be demonstrated by something more than "my opinion is..." (vs. "a fatwa says...").

Comment: does my edit good enough ?

Comment: Tegar your question has great potential if you follow Rebecca’s advice. Re-think it and re-post it.

Answer (score 2):

The acronym LGBT does not appear in any classical Islamic text, or for that matter, any text written in any language before the 1990s (which is, as you can tell, *very recent*, compared to thousands of years of world history). Even today, many world languages do not have a word for gay or LGBT, etc. and simply use the English, because the concept is foreign to them.

From a classical/traditional Islamic point of view, **sex is something that people do, not something that people are.** So while people can have sexual urges of all different kinds, and may choose to act or not to act upon them, those sexual urges (or lack thereof) ***do not define them***.

1. **Islamically, certain things are forbidden when it comes to sex**; e.g.
   having sex with a sibling, having sex with a woman who is already
   married, having sex with someone you are not married to (regardless of the sex), **and having sex with someone of the same sex as you**. To do any of these actions would be considered haram (i.e. sinful).
2. **People are not held accountable for their inclinations or desires; or anything that is beyond their control** You might have an inclination to eat in Ramadan during daylight hours, but that's not a sin unless you actively decide to act upon that desire. You might have an inclination to sleep in and miss the dawn (Fajr) prayer, but that's not a sin unless you decide to act accordingly. The same is true about sexual sins, whether it be having illicit sex with someone from the opposite sex or the same sex. It's a sin when you act upon it.
3. In Islam, it is a sin to pry into other people's private lives; ***so what people do in the privacy of their own homes is their own business*** (again whether it be drinking alcohol, having illicit sex with someone from the opposite sex, or illicit sex with someone from the same sex, or anything else.)

So, all in all:

1. The college has no right to pry into the students' private lives.
2. The college shouldn't punish the students' for their inclinations/desires, if there is no evidence that a haram action has taken place.
3. If the students in question actively and publicly endorse a haram lifestyle, and the college is an islamic college (whose main purpose is to instil islamic values), then they would have the right to insist on islamic values, and to take action accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Islam only says to refrain from your desires, so this isn't a Muslim issue, rather it's either cultural, or simply ignorance.

Comment: That doesn’t answer the question. I’m not down voting because the question is unorganized, but this is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Narrated Abu Hurairah: that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "Whoever
> takes a path upon which to obtain knowledge, Allah makes the path to
> Paradise easy for him." https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2646

Whatever be a person's orientation we should not deny education to anyone because education will make the path to paradise easy for him. A person's orientation itself is not making him sin but acting upon any orientation which result in forbidden (haram) act is making him sin. Just like a straight man/woman who is unmarried, divorced or separated, if s/he act upon his/her orientation to do adulatory (zina) , s/he is sinning, likewise LBGT person who act upon their orientation to do forbidden acts they are sinning.